# How do I load a script dynamically via Backbone?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

Inside one of my views, I'd like to load this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain.com" id="hello" name="abc"></script>
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Search for `using Backbone.js with Require.js`.

Comment: Require.js in charge of loading scripts, follow  Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui advice

Comment: You could also append the script tag manually to the head or use `$.getScript()` (which does pretty much the same). For just a single script, RequireJS ist too much overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Manually appending it:

   ```
   $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain.com" id="hello" name="abc"></script>')
   ```
2. Using `$.getScript`:

   ```
   $.getScript('https://domain.com').done(function () {
       // loaded!
   });
   ```
3. [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org):

   ```
   require.config({
       paths: {
           "myscript": "https://domain.com"
       }
   });

   require(['myscript'], function () {
       // loaded!
   });
   ```

Comment: How can I set those variables in the script like name and id? (that APi requires me to do so.)

Comment: 1. allows you to do that; this is not possible in 2. & 3. though.